# Dropdown that connects with database when clicked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Normally when the page loads, the dropdown is loaded with values. But is it possible to make a dropdown that will only load values from database when the dropdown button is clicked? I need this to insert the most updated values in the dropdown; since from other page the contents of the the dropdown can be modified.

Currently this is my dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Purchase_Tax, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PTList"], new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: have you tried with binding it to a source(for example a datatable?)

Comment: I edited my post. Currently i am connecting the dropdown using that viewData list; in the controller the PTList gets data from database.

Comment: Explore using javascript and AJAX to update the dropdown list when the user click on the dropdown.